# Issue with Show/Hide function in jQuery. Jumps to top of page

Tags: jquery, html, click, hide

I'm using the click/hide function for my questions and answers page. But when I click on the question to show the answer it jumps back up to the top. What do I need to do to get this to stop.

This is my coding:

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".sub").hide();
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
jQuery(".cthrough").click(function()
{
jQuery(this).next(".sub").slideToggle(500);
});});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.cthrough {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Anaheim', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.sub {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="cthrough">This is my question</a>
<div class="sub">
    This is my answer.
</div>
```

I have tried converting the a href=# to just a div class but that doesn't make the question clickable. I also tried taking the # out but that didn't help either.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but relevant to the topic:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0/138233#138233

Answer (score 4):

Keep your `href="#"` and use [jQuery's `.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent the default action of jumping back to the top.

```
jQuery(".cthrough").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // <-- first line
    jQuery(this).next(".sub").slideToggle(500);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Tessa Wilde, please reward Sparky for his answer!

Answer (score 1):

The root cause with `#` in `href`. If the URL contains `#` followed by div name, then user will be landed in that `div`. This is the browser's default behaviour, In above case when click that URL `#` is appended to root URL, that's why it takes to top of the page.

To fix this remove `href="#"` and use `style="cursor: pointer"` to keep the hand/pointer symbol to that link.

Instead of `<a href="#" class="cthrough">This is my question</a>`
Use `<a class="cthrough">This is my question</a>`
and add the `cursor: pointer` style to that class(`.cthrough`).

Answer (score 0):

Having the same trouble and `e.preventDefault()` not working for me if I apply duration to say a `slideDown()`.

Kind of hacky, but this works for me.
The browser freaks out trying to figure the size of the element you're showing during the animation.
So, I show it right away, now the browser knows it's size.
But with low opacity, and then I just fade it in.

```
// show/hide jobs section
$('.job').hide();

$('a.jobTrigger').click(function(e){
    $('.job').hide();
    $(this).next('.job').show(0, function() {
        
        //animation to stop page jump
        $(this).css('opacity' , '.1');
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //keeps hash out of URL
});
```